# react-router v1.0.0 Cannot Reach Routes

Tags: react-router

I've been working with `react-router` for a project at work and for some reason It cannot reach routes besides the `IndexRoute`. When attempting to reach the `/profile` route it returns this in the browser:

[Response In Browser](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/8888991/11325589/c3dac9fa-911f-11e5-893b-15c60f6ceb98.png)

I'm trying to use react-router for client-side routing.

Heres my code for my routes:

```js
let history = createBrowserHistory();

render((
    <Router history={history} >
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={Landing}/>
            <Route path="profile" component={UserProfile}/>
         </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

I thought it may have been the `UserProfile` component but when I plugged it into the `IndexRoute` it rendered properly. No errors show up in the console, I'm hoping the issue is something that is obvious that I overlooked, any and all help is welcome.

Comment: what server are you using to serve your React app?

Comment: Im using webpack-dev-server and react-hot-load @knowbody